# JSON data is returning empty cell in detailViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I've a **collectionViewCell**(dynamic) with images and **labels** (loading from `JSON`) inside a tableview. what i want is if i click on any Cell (contains image/folders) it should display **detailedViewController**  with its content(also from `JSON`).
 my **mainViewController**  works fine. displays the DATA.

inside **mainViewController** i used **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   println("USER TAPPED item# \(indexPath.item)")
   let subFolderView:SubFolderViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("subFolder") as! SubFolderViewController
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subFolderView, animated: true)
   subFolderView.imageSelected = self.Data[indexPath.row].AbsolutePath
   subFolderView.imageSelected = self.Data[indexPath.row].Name
   subFolderView.imageSelected = self.Data[indexPath.row].Description
```

BUT it is returning empty view when clicked.

in my **secondViewController** i have

```
var imageSelected:String!

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell:SubFolderCollectionViewCell? = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SubFolderCollectionViewCell
    cell?.subFolderDescription.text = self.Data[indexPath.row].Description
    cell?.subFolderName.text = self.Data[indexPath.row].Name

    let picUrl = self.Data[indexPath.row].AbsolutePath
    let url = NSURL(string: picUrl)
    if(url != nil) {  
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL : url!)
        if(data != nil) {
            cell?.subImage?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Please any one guide me to proceed further......i am new to iOS development  and  prefer swift!!!!!!!

IN my **storyBoadrd** both **viewControllers** contains

> **View**,
>
> **Tableview**,
>
> **TableViewCell**,
>
> **ContentView**,
>
> **collectionView**,
>
> **collectionViewCell**.
>
> inside that **imageView** and **labels** to display the data

Any help is appreciated,
Please let me know if u need more code............

Comment: What's `subFolderView.imageSelected`?

Comment: json is not related tag here i feel.

Comment: @anhtu subFolder.ImageSelected those are my json response data

Comment: Why did you edit it 3 times:`subFolderView.imageSelected = self.Data[indexPath.row].AbsolutePath
   subFolderView.imageSelected = self.Data[indexPath.row].Name
   subFolderView.imageSelected = self.Data[indexPath.row].Description`? And why using `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: well i used didSelectItemIndexPath also..no use ...

Comment: @anhtu: here i am passing content,its  name and description(as labels)

Comment: @JB29.4 If you pass like that. `subFolderView.imageSelected` just has `Description` value?

Comment: content along with its name and description..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code..

you use **didDeselectItemAtIndexPath** instead of **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** method..

It's different tableview delegate method. change this and let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Please provide screenshot of your layout with side bar for more specification.